# Multimeter Always Reads 60Hz Measuring a CD4060 Pierce Oscillator

Tags: oscillator, frequency, multimeter

Using a CD4060 IC [I’ve built a crystal oscillator circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/474494/finding-quartz-crystal-datasheets-and-choosing-resistors-for-pierce-oscillators) similar to the one in the image. [I’m trying to use my klein mm400 multimeter to measure the oscillation frequency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/474309/tool-for-measuring-the-frequency-of-a-crystal-oscillator) so I can get a rough estimate.

Where should I be placing the probes in that net? I’ve tried placing both across a resistor connected to the output pin, but the meter always reads 60Hz.

Perhaps the messy wires are disturbing the probes? This circuit looks horrendous because I don’t have any resistors larger than 1M.. I should really cut these cables too to shorten them.

[image: picture of my messy circuit]
**This is not my actual schematic** but my circuit is set up the same way. I am using 22pF caps, 47k for Rs
[image: schematic]

Update: **My circuit is now corrected and oscillates reliably but the multimeter still has the same issue. Read my answer down below to see my new circuit.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103010/discussion-on-question-by-strugglingstudent117-multimeter-always-reads-60hz-meas). Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).